# How can I reference a generic struct inside another struct without making the latter be generic?

Tags: generics, rust

To wit:

```
use std::fmt;

// Element types
const INTEGER: &'static str = "INTEGER";
const FLOAT: &'static str = "FLOAT";
const STRING: &'static str = "STRING";

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Element<T> {
    mt_type: &'static str,
    mt_value: T,
}
impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for Element<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Element({}, {})", self.mt_type, self.mt_value)
    }
}

struct Parser {
    text: String,
    pos: usize,
    current_element: Element, // Here there should be something to hold different Elements at different times...
}
```

I would need `current_element` to hold a `Element<i64>`, a `Element<f64>`, and a `Element<String>` in the same struct at different times; I was reading the Rust guide and it seems that all solutions point towards making the struct `Parser` generic, yet if I do that then at run-time I am committed to use a different `Parser` for a different `Element` type.

An ugly way to solve this is to get all values inside `Element` as strings and then convert them to the proper type when needed, but then the overhead would be big...

Comment: You cannot — Rust sizes structs based on their members, so an `Element<String>` has a different size from `Element<i64>`. When you put an `Element` into your `Parser`, then the size of the `Parser` depends on the generic type. The alternative is to have a single type that represents all possibilities. A *trait object* or an enum would be the go-to choices.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for pointing me to the right answer.